# Which warp points go where (and have ambushes) in Chapter 6 before and after the lever is thrown?

Tags: fire-emblem-three-houses

I'm on the Golden Deer route if it matters chapter 6 map, I'm looking to reduce my stress as I've found this Fire Emblem to have a lot of good and a lot of bad/unpleasant. I'm looking for a visual guide/map as to which warp points take you where before and after the lever is thrown. Fun surprises like knowing a certain warp point takes you into an ambush is handy to know as well.

I already threw the lever and now there looks like there are even more warp points!

Answer (score 2):

I found a map, google failed, so ironically I used bing.

https://gamewith.net/fire-emblem-three-houses/article/show/10351

[image]

Comment: "Google failed." Really? That's the top link for me when searching `three houses chapter 6 warp`